# Why the property not found in the repository section?

Tags: maven

I have a `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-base</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.0.pr1</version>
  </parent>

  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
  <version>2.10.0.pr1</version>
  <name>jackson-databind</name>
  <packaging>bundle</packaging>
  <description>General data-binding functionality for Jackson: works on core streaming API</description>
  <url>http://github.com/FasterXML/jackson</url>
  <inceptionYear>2008</inceptionYear>

  <scm>
    <connection>scm:git:git@github.com:FasterXML/jackson-databind.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:FasterXML/jackson-databind.git</developerConnection>
    <url>http://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind</url>
    <tag>jackson-databind-2.10.0.pr1</tag>
  </scm>

  <properties>
    <!-- With Jackson 2.10 baseline is JDK 7 (except for annotations/streaming),
         and new language features (diamond pattern) may be used.
         JDK classes are still loaded dynamically since there isn't much downside
         (small number of types); this allows use on JDK 6 platforms still (including
         Android)
      -->
    <javac.src.version>1.7</javac.src.version>
    <javac.target.version>1.7</javac.target.version>

    <!-- Can not use default, since group id != Java package name here -->
    <osgi.export>com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.*;version=${project.version}</osgi.export>
    <!-- fix for databind#2299: using jackson-databind in an OSGi environment under Android --> 
    <osgi.import>
        org.w3c.dom.bootstrap;resolution:=optional,
        *
    </osgi.import>

    <!-- Generate PackageVersion.java into this directory. -->
    <packageVersion.dir>com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg</packageVersion.dir>
    <packageVersion.package>com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.cfg</packageVersion.package>

    <version.powermock>2.0.0</version.powermock>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- Builds on core streaming API; also needs core annotations -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
      <!-- 06-Mar-2017, tatu: Although bom provides for dependencies, some legacy
             usage seems to benefit from actually specifying version here in case
             it is dependent on transitively
        -->
      <version>${jackson.version.annotations}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
      <version>${jackson.version.core}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- and for testing we need a few libraries
         libs for which we use reflection for code, but direct dep for testing
      -->

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
      <artifactId>powermock-core</artifactId>
      <version>${version.powermock}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
      <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
      <version>${version.powermock}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
      <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
      <version>${version.powermock}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- For testing TestNoClassDefFoundDeserializer -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.measure</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsr-275</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <!-- Alas, need to include snapshot reference since otherwise can not find
       snapshot of parent... -->
  <repositories>
<!--    <repository>-->
<!--      <id>sonatype-nexus-snapshots</id>-->
<!--      <name>Sonatype Nexus Snapshots</name>-->
<!--      <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>-->
<!--      <releases><enabled>false</enabled></releases>-->
<!--      <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>-->
<!--    </repository>-->
    <repository>
      <id>example-repo</id>
      <name>Example Repository</name>
      <url>file:/${project.basedir}/libs</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <build>
     <plugins>
      <!-- Important: enable enforcer plug-in: -->
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions> <!-- or?  combine.children="merge"> -->
          <execution>
            <id>enforce-properties</id>
        <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals><goal>enforce</goal></goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <version>${version.plugin.surefire}</version>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <classpathDependencyExcludes>
            <exclude>javax.measure:jsr-275</exclude>
          </classpathDependencyExcludes>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>com/fasterxml/jackson/failing/*.java</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <!-- parent definitions should be ok, but need to add more links -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <links combine.children="append">
            <link>http://fasterxml.github.com/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.10</link>
            <link>http://fasterxml.github.com/jackson-core/javadoc/2.10</link>
          </links>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <!-- settings are fine, but needed to trigger execution! -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>replacer</artifactId>
      </plugin>

      <!--  04-Mar-2019, tatu: Add rudimentary JDK9+ module info. To build with JDK 8
             will have to use `moduleInfoFile` as anything else requires JDK 9+
        -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.moditect</groupId>
        <artifactId>moditect-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>

       <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>3.2.0</version>
         <executions>
           <execution>
             <id>copy-dependencies</id>
             <phase>package</phase>
             <goals>
               <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
             </goals>
             <configuration>
               <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/libs</outputDirectory>
               <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
               <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
               <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
             </configuration>
           </execution>
         </executions>
       </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>release</id>
      <properties>
        <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
        <skipTests>true</skipTests>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

</project>
```

I need to build the project completely offline and for that have a `/libs` directory with all dependencies there. As you can see `${project.basedir}/libs` works fine in `maven-dependency-plugin` but it fails in the "repository" section with following error:

```
mvn install
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading from example-repo: file:/${project.basedir}/libs/com/fasterxml/jackson/jackson-base/2.10.0.pr1/jackson-base-2.10.0.pr1.pom
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/jackson-base/2.10.0.pr1/jackson-base-2.10.0.pr1.pom
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.0.pr1:
        Could not transfer artifact com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-base:pom:2.10.0.pr1
        from/to example-repo (file:/${project.basedir}/libs):
        Repository path /${project.basedir}/libs does not exist, and cannot be created.
        and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 5, column 11
```

Could you tell me why `file:/${project.basedir}/libs` doesn't work?

Comment: Why are you trying to build a local repository (or a libs directory) instead of using the default mechanisms of Maven? What kind of problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @khmarbaise I need a local folder as only repository

Comment: Am not sure whether you can resolve this at all, but for a protocol like `file`, you need to put two slashes after the `:`.

Comment: I haven't asked about your configuration (created libs directory etc.) I have asked what kind of problem you have or what you are trying to solve to make such a strange configuration...

Comment: @J Fabian Meier look, Maven can't handle ${project.basedir} property somehow, do you know why?

Comment: @khmarbaise there are the problem requirements.

Comment: @EkaterinaIvanovaiceja.net What do you mean by "there are the problem requirements"? Why do you need to build "completely offline"? What exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: Follow the convention over configuration paradigm of Maven and do not use a lib directory because that's not the Maven it handles nor does it makes sense...(without any explanation I can not guess/think why you need that)...

Comment: @J Fabian Meier I need to add a flat directory as Maven repository, the only one repository. Please tell me, how to do that?

Comment: @khmarbaise it is all that I can say, the rest of project is covered by NDA

Comment: 1. Build the project with an empty local repository on a machine with internet. 2. Copy the content to some fixed directory and put its path as repository into your settings.xml.

Comment: @J Fabian Meier thank you!! What if I need to build about 40 projects in same environment? Should I build all of them, then copy content of ~/.m2 ??

Comment: @EkaterinaIvanovaiceja.net If your projects have different dependencies then: yes.

Comment: See [How to add local jar files to a Maven project?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4955635/1744774).